# Cleaning up the data created during the script

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

1. Am calling a http create api endpoint to create few records in the ***setup*** thread group.
2. Performing action on those records
3. Trying to call the delete api endpoint to clear the records before script exit in the ***teardown*** threadgroup

However what am noticing is that sometimes the deletion of the record happens before all the other threads exit  during load tests. Is there a way to ensure that this doesnt happen.

My Jmeter version is 5.3.
Am running 6 jmeter servers in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a single JMeter instance the execution order is:

- setup Thread Group
- Thread Group
- tearDown ThreadGroup

Your issue comes from distributed test where this order is not guaranteed across instances.

You could use a 3rd party like a Database + [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) that would be called to do the sync:

- Call it to notify start for a worker from setup TG
- Call it at start of teardown TG, it will hold until all have ended
- This way teardown Thread Group will be called after all thread of Main Thread Group has ended

Comment: Thanks. However am wondering how this is possible as each of these servers that are running parallely are generating data independent of each other and uses only the data that it generates. So in effect its 6 independent instances that should ideally respect the setup and tear down thread groups.

Comment: Yes and my answer takes this into account, the 3rd party element will guarantee that teardown TG starts only when all servers have finished

Comment: Thank you. Problems i have with this solution that i cant seem to get around right now
1) Currently i have a specified no of Setup TG threads and only 1 tearDown TG thread. So ill have to figure out how to keep the flags value consistent for each thread.
2) The cloud VM on which i run the test doesnt have access to the db host . (Only api)

Apologies if sound confusing.

Comment: I was able to use your solution. Changed the setup and tearDown to have a single thread  and used a if controller to check a jmeter property value before tearDown. Appreciate your help.